# Brother, CUPS and custom paper size

Tags: cups

Does anybody know how Brother does to add custom paper sizes without modifying the PPD?
They have a utility with the following usage:

```
 CUPS Paper Size Tool (v 0.1)   Copyright by 2005-2013
 Usage: brpapertoolcups -P Printer Name [-n add a Label Format Name (<=32 bytes) -w Media Width(unit:mm) -h Media Height(unit:mm)]/[-d delete Label Format Name]
 For example:
 1. Add a new Label Format with "New Label Format" name and 29mm width and 70mm length:
    "brpapertoolcups -P ql550 -n New\ Label\ Format -w 29 -h 70" [enter]

 2. Remove the Label Format with "New Label Format" name:
    "brpapertoolcups -P ql550 -d New\ Label\ Format" [enter]
```

I've been taking a look at the PPD of the printer and there's no custom paper defined there.
Does CUPS have another way to load custom paper sizes for a printer apart from the PPD?

Comment: What type of file is `brpapertoolcups`? Use `file $(type -p brpapertoolcups)`. If it's a script, read it with `less $(type -p brpapertoolcups)`, and read the `man` page for the interpreter (on line 1 of the script). Otherwise, investigate the file with `ldd`, `strings`, `readelf`. Read their `man` pages.

Comment: Here it is:
`./brpapertoolcups: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.2.5, stripped`
It creates bin files for each defined paper type in a specific directory and adds specific information regarding the custom paper in several text files.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. StackExchange  is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].